# Do I really need to submit an app request to facebook in order to use the fb-api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have a site where I need to manually specify the content (and Url since some parameters need to be added depending on which facebook share link i press) in the facebook share-dialouge. I've got it to work now as developer but do I really need to submit an app request for the "app" and thereby create an "my app page" on facebook for the "app"? (I have a business page for my business)

All I want to do is use the facebook api to share my page content. Please give me an explanation for dummies because I'm getting really tired of Facebook right now.

(No I can't use addThis)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't need to create an app page and the "request" will be immediately processed.

Comment: So the "app-page" is voluntarily after the submission? It won't be created by default?

Comment: I got a dozen of "apps" and never made an app page. Even if I would have one I don't think anyone can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you don't confuse some stuff. have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share to get an overview about sharing on the FB platform.

You can use the Social Plugins for your Use Case I guess:

- Share Button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/
- Share Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I'm not mistaken it still requires an app id which means that I have to submit an application?

Comment: No you don't need to submit the app to get an app id. You can read about the review process here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#review

Comment: Exactly. You can use the app without submission. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Comment: Don't know how you found those support pages but they helped a lot with understanding when you ned to submit the app and when you don't have to.

Comment: Well I'm still pretty confused. I created an app just to get an `app_id` for the sharing dialog, but it only works when I'm logged in with the developer FB a/c. To submit for review I'm going to have to jump over yet more hurdles, but I don't really want a searchable app just to open a sharing dialog... Unless it's intended that you take the `app_id` straight from the examples [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web)? `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895...`