# How to create a Facebook App that will be used just for the "share dialog"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-settings

I want to create a Facebook "share" link to post a score from a HTML game. The old `/sharer.php` method would be ideal but there's no way to suggest text along with the post (and this method is deprecated AFAIK).

The recommended way I'm struggling with is the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect). I've created an app and have an `app_id` but I'm unable to get this to work without submitting for review. Unless I'm logged in as the developer I just get an error page that reads:

"An error occurred. Please try later"

I don't want the app to be searchable on FB. I don't want to install the FB JS SDK (completely overkill for what can be a link/redirect). "Submit for review" requires details for Facebook Login, which is not used, so I'm unsure how to proceed with this.

Also possibly relevant, I can't seem to add "website" as a App Centre listed platform ("either configured incorrectly or not supported by the App Centre").

Has anyone done this before? Do I really need to submit the app, and how? I'm trying to find the least crufty, least effortful way to do this ultra-simple thing ;) Any help/advice appreciated.

**N.B., prior art:**

[Do I really need to submit an app request to facebook in order to use the fb-api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343203/do-i-really-need-to-submit-an-app-request-to-facebook-in-order-to-use-the-fb-api)

This question is similar but either the advice given is out of date or for the questioner was solved using a share button (unclear which). Other questions I've found seem to be concerning other contexts of use (Android, FB SDK etc).

Comment: If you are downvoting please lease constructive feedback, thanks.

Comment: The Share dialog doesn’t need any permissions, it doesn’t even require the user to login to your app – so there _is_ nothing to send in for review in such a case. And if you are getting errors, it would be helpful if you mentioned what that error message says exactly …

Comment: _“I don't want the app to be searchable on FB”_ – you will need to set it to “publicly available” though, otherwise users without a role in the app won’t be able to use it, and any content created through it won’t be visible to normal users either.

Comment: Thanks, good point. Updated above, the error reads "An error occurred. Please try later".

Comment: So far I've not found a way to make it publically available, other than the review process. If it has to be publically available that's okay, I just thought it might be confusing to users to find an "app" that's basically a shell for some Facebook functionality.

Comment: Setting the app public just requires to toggle the switch on top of the Status&Review->Status tab in app dashboard; it does not require review.

Comment: @CBroe got it, thanks for your pointers/time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't have been too surprised this wasn't working because the app was marked as in "development mode" (so only accessible to the users nominated under Roles). What was less clear was how to disable this mode, fortunately I found this question/answer combo:

[The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login)

Entering a contact email address for the app enabled the "set live" toggle on the Status and Review page. In case you think I'm an idiot (and the jury is out on this), I didn't see any messages or warnings to indicate this was an issue, though turns out there is a tooltip on the toggle button to advise of this.